# How to create a TCP Server using RInside?

Tags: r, tcp, rinside

Does anyone has an experience in creating a TCP server in C++ for calling R functions and serving the results to the clients?

I implemented my own using POCO C++ libraries, but got an error message which led me to see the fact that RInside can not be used in a multi-threaded application.

I think this is non-sense. Ok, R itself is single threaded but there should be a way of creating a server in C++ and RInside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want [Rserve](http://rforge.net/Rserve) which has been doing this for a decade, rather than starting something new with our [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html) -- though you could look at my RInside/Wt example for a webapp...

Comment: Well, when I reviewed my question, something sparkled. Rserve could have been there for a decade as you said and many people could have been using it for a long time. However, is it the best choice in terms of scalability and performance? What do you think @Dirk? I'm not an R expert, but would like to get most of its capabilities over the network.